# Access XML using variables in android

Tags: android, android-xml

I want access to a picture using

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo1);
```

How can I change "photo1" to "photo" + # (incremented number) so that I can use it with an iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("photo"+1,"drawable", getPackageName());
image.setImageResource(resID);
```